# take the last value in data frame by factor category

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
a=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D")
b=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2)
c=c(1345,645,75,8,95,678,598,95,75,4,53)
mydf <- data.frame(a,b,c) # edit note: do _not_ use cbind inside data.frame
```

My aim is to get add an extra column on the new data frame which will take the last value of column "c" taking into account the factor in column "a".
More specifically, in this examlpe the end result is like this:

```
   a b    c   d
1  A 1 1345   0
2  A 2  645   0
3  A 3   75   0
4  A 4    8   8
5  B 1   95   0
6  B 2  678 678
7  C 1  598   0
8  C 2   95   0
9  C 3   75  75
10 D 1    4   0
11 D 2   53  53
```

Comment: I tried `mydf$d=ave(mydf$c,mydf$a,FUN=function(x) c(rep(0,length(x)-1),x[length(x)]))` but i got an error message of invalid times argument

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need your variables to be all fators, there's a nice solution with `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D"),
                 b=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2),
                 c=c(1345,645,75,8,95,678,598,95,75,4,53),stringsAsFactors = F)    

library(dplyr)

df <- tbl_df(df)

df  %>% group_by(a)%>%
  mutate(d = ifelse(b == max(b),c[which(b == max(b))],0))



# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   a [4]
       a     b     c     d
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     A     1  1345     0
 2     A     2   645     0
 3     A     3    75     0
 4     A     4     8     8
 5     B     1    95     0
 6     B     2   678   678
 7     C     1   598     0
 8     C     2    95     0
 9     C     3    75    75
10     D     1     4     0
11     D     2    53    53
```

Comment: Probably more efficient to do `mutate(d = ifelse(row_number() == n() , c, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
 library(data.table) 
 df <- data.frame(a,b,c)    
 setDT(df)
 df[, idx := .N, by = a]
 df[, id := 1:.N, by = a]
 df <- df[id == idx, d := c]
 df[, c("id", "idx") := NULL]
 df[is.na(df)] <- 0

    a b    c   d
 1: A 1 1345   0
 2: A 2  645   0
 3: A 3   75   0
 4: A 4    8   8
 5: B 1   95   0
 6: B 2  678 678
 7: C 1  598   0
 8: C 2   95   0
 9: C 3   75  75
10: D 1    4   0
11: D 2   53  53
```

Comment: Do not let the dangerous use of `as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c)) ` go uncorrected. It is a very common source of obscure errors that trip up newbies.

Comment: No need for `id` and `idx`. You can do `df[, d := c*(1:.N == .N), by = a]`